# Can't see the data inside a dataScroller's ng-template of PrimeNG

Tags: angular2-template, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG module in my Angular 2 app.
I used the dataSrollerModule and the datas are displayed inside it's header but not inside it's ng-template.

Also I have this error : 
**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined**.(But I see the data)
This error is displayed before this.pages.length.

To better understand here u are the code and tnx in advance :

Component :

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'view-batch',
 templateUrl: './view-batch.component.html'
})
 export class ViewBatchComponent implements OnInit {

@Output()
onDocumentSelected = new EventEmitter<any>();
load: boolean;
pages =[];

constructor(
private errorService: ErrorService,
private batchService: BatchService,
) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.batchService.getPageStreamById(8653).subscribe(pageStream => {
  if(this.pages){
   this.pages = []; 
         }
  this.pages.push({data:'test'});
  console.log("this.pages.length :" + this.pages.length)// It displays 1
})
```

}

Html :

```
<p-dataScroller [value]="pages" [rows]="10" [inline]="true">
   <p-header>{{pages[0].data}}</p-header> // here I see data but in the 
     //console notify me that at this line it cant read property  'data' of 
     //undefined

  <ng-template let-page pTemplate="item">
    <span>{{pages[0].data}}</span>// nothing
    <span>{{page.data}}</span>//nothing
 </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error because  code '{{pages[0].data}}' is rendering before you are pushing data into 'pages' array at line this.pages.push({data:'test'}); . Rendering is happening before push.

As per code pages =[]; . Initially the array is empty so accessing zero index pages[0] will give you undefined hence the error 'Cannot read property 'data' of undefined'

You need to make two correction in code to make it work -

First one is that don't let data scroller render before data is available in pages array by applying ngIf. 
Second is that don't use push method to push data in array as push does not trigger change detection cycle instead use spread method.

Here is the code

Html -

```
<p-dataScroller  *ngIf ='scrollerDataLoaded'   // won't render until data is available
                 [value]="pages" 
                 [rows]="10" [inline]="true">
    <p-header>{{pages[0].data}}</p-header> // if html render before data is loaded then for an empty array pages[0] is undefined.
    <ng-template let-page pTemplate="item">
       <span>{{pages[0].data}}</span>// nothing
       <span>{{page.data}}</span>//nothing
    </ng-template>
```

Coponent -

```
scrollerDataLoaded : boolean = false;
ngOnInit() {
   this.batchService.getPageStreamById(8653).subscribe(pageStream => {
     if(this.pages){
        this.pages = []; 
     }
     //this.pages.push({data:'test'}); don't use push
     this.pages = [...this.pages, {data:'test'}]; // use spread operator to push data. this will trigger change detection.
     console.log("this.pages.length :" + this.pages.length)
     this.scrollerDataLoaded =true; // html will render after setting this to true and pages array will have data as well.
   })
```

Comment: Hello, now I have multiple data in this.pages.When I do console.log(this.pages) I see 10 element but I see just one element in the datascroller.   Any Idea please?

Comment: In <ng-template let-page , page is a variable through which scroller is iterating so don't use pages[0].data, instead use page.data in html. also you can remove service call and feed multiple dummy objects in pages array just to test.